# unable to access mailpile server inside docker container

Tags: docker

I have created a docker container and have installed the mailpile open source email client.
Running the mailpile binary inside the container prints the following message to STDOUT.

`The Web interface address is: http://localhost:33411/`

So I opened firefox on the host machine and tried `127.0.0.1:33411`. It did not work.
Then I looked up the IP address assigned to the container by docker. 
I looked it up by running the following command on the host,
`docker inspect mp | grep IP`

It said the container had an IP address of 172.17.0.3

So now, I tried `172.17.0.3:33411` on firefox running on my host. It still didn't work.

So then I stopped the container with `docker stop mp`. And then I committed it to an image under the name `mp_image`. I ran the following command on the host to do the commit.

`docker commit mp mp_image`

After the commit, I created a new running container, but this time forwarded port 33411 of the container to port 33411 of the host. I ran the following command on host,

`docker run -i -t -p 33411:33411 --name "mailpile" mp_image /bin/bash`

And now, once I got inside the container, ran the mailpile binary again and tried accessing it from the host. This time I used all these variations on the host browser,

`127.0.0.1:33411`
`172.17.0.3:33411`

Again not working. Now I started doubting if the server was running in the container in the first place. So I went inside the container and did `wget 127.0.0.1:33411`. And I got a nice `index.html` file. So the server is running..

I don't know what to do at this point. Can someone please advice?

Comment: enter in your container with `docker exec`and check with `netstat -an` and similar commands

Comment: `Active Internet connections (servers and established)`
`Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      `
 `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33411         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Answer (score 0):

Mailpile is built to listen on port 33411 from the local host only. Install a proxy or tunnel a connection as described here: https://github.com/mailpile/Mailpile/wiki/Accessing-The-GUI-Over-Internet